# App Open Ad shows after Intent was called in onActivityResult, how to stop it

Tags: android, ads, google-mobile-ads

I implemented AppOpen to my project, it works fine.
Here's the code:

```
public class AppOpenManager implements LifecycleObserver, Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {
private static final String LOG_TAG = "AppOpenManager";
private static String AD_UNIT_ID;
private AppOpenAd appOpenAd = null;
private static boolean isShowingAd = false;
public static boolean shouldOpenAd = true;

private AppOpenAd.AppOpenAdLoadCallback loadCallback;
private Activity currentActivity;
private long loadTime = 0;
private final UILApplication myApplication;

public AppOpenManager(UILApplication myApplication, boolean isPurchased) {
    AD_UNIT_ID = AdsConstants.getAppOpenId(myApplication.getApplicationContext());

    this.myApplication = myApplication;
    this.myApplication.registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);
    ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().getLifecycle().addObserver(this);
    shouldOpenAd = !isPurchased;
}

/**
 * LifecycleObserver methods
 */
@OnLifecycleEvent(ON_START)
public void onStart() {
    if (shouldOpenAd)
        showAdIfAvailable();
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onStart");
}

/**
 * Request an ad
 */
public void fetchAd() {
    // Have unused ad, no need to fetch another.
    if (isAdAvailable()) {
        return;
    }

    loadCallback = new AppOpenAd.AppOpenAdLoadCallback() {
        /**
         * Called when an app open ad has loaded.
         * @param ad the loaded app open ad.
         */
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull AppOpenAd ad) {
            AppOpenManager.this.appOpenAd = ad;
            AppOpenManager.this.loadTime = (new Date()).getTime();
            Log.d("OnAdLoaded", "Banner adapter class name: " + ad.getResponseInfo().getMediationAdapterClassName());
        }

        /**
         * Called when an app open ad has failed to load.
         * @param loadAdError the error.
         */
        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {
            // Handle the error.
        }

    };
    AdRequest request = getAdRequest();
    AppOpenAd.load(
            myApplication, AD_UNIT_ID, request,
            AppOpenAd.APP_OPEN_AD_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT, loadCallback);
}

/**
 * Shows the ad if one isn't already showing.
 */
public void showAdIfAvailable() {
    // Only show ad if there is not already an app open ad currently showing
    // and an ad is available.
    if (!isShowingAd && isAdAvailable()) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Will show ad.");

        FullScreenContentCallback fullScreenContentCallback =
                new FullScreenContentCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                        // Set the reference to null so isAdAvailable() returns false.
                        AppOpenManager.this.appOpenAd = null;
                        isShowingAd = false;
                        fetchAd();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(AdError adError) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
                        isShowingAd = true;
                    }
                };

        appOpenAd.setFullScreenContentCallback(fullScreenContentCallback);
        appOpenAd.show(currentActivity);

    } else {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Can not show ad.");
        fetchAd();
    }
}

/**
 * Creates and returns ad request.
 */
private AdRequest getAdRequest() {
    return new AdRequest.Builder().build();
}

/**
 * Utility method that checks if ad exists and can be shown.
 */
public boolean isAdAvailable() {
    return appOpenAd != null && wasLoadTimeLessThanNHoursAgo(4);
}

/**
 * Utility method to check if ad was loaded more than n hours ago.
 */
private boolean wasLoadTimeLessThanNHoursAgo(long numHours) {
    long dateDifference = (new Date()).getTime() - this.loadTime;
    long numMilliSecondsPerHour = 3600000;
    return (dateDifference < (numMilliSecondsPerHour * numHours));
}
//some listeners here
}
```

The only problem is that I have Activity Result:

```
 someActivityResultLauncher = fragment.registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            result -> {
                if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    Intent data = result.getData();
                    if (data != null) {
                        ArrayList<Uri> uriList = new ArrayList<>();
                        if (data.getClipData() != null) {
                            int count = data.getClipData().getItemCount();
                            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                                Uri uri = data.getClipData().getItemAt(i).getUri();
                                uriList.add(uri);
                            }
                        } else if (data.getData() != null) {
                            Uri uri = data.getData();
                            uriList.add(uri);
                        }
                        intentServiceSendingFileUtils.createIntentForSendingFile(fragment.requireActivity(),
                                uriList, info);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Every time I want to select pictures/documents/etc. AppOpen Ad appears.
How to prevent my app from doing this?

I want to show App Open Ad only when my app opens or user goes back.
I can set some boolean value to true/false to show or not the ad but maybe there is any better solution for this.

Comment: i suppose the "problem" is caused by the fact that you're doing all of this in the application class, which is probably a fine place to do it usually, but for this one case now it doesn't work like you want it to, and that's how the library was designed, but like you said, i think the best you can do would be to set some sort of flag somewhere, perhaps an additional check inside `showAdIfAvailable` to make sure that ads aren't shown when you don't want them to, perhaps a static flag you can set before and after starting the intent perhaps

Comment: @a_local_nobody that's a pity but thank you for your ideas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

okay, fixed, maybe anyone needs this:

```
@OnLifecycleEvent(ON_START)
    public void onStart() {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "onStart isSelectingFile --> " + isSelectingFile);

        if (shouldOpenAd && !isSelectingFile) {
            showAdIfAvailable();
        } else if (isSelectingFile)
            isSelectingFile = false;
    }
```

and

```
 private void getContent(String type) {
        AppOpenManager.isSelectingFile = true;

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
        intent.setType(type);
        someActivityResultLauncher.launch(intent);
    }
```

Just set the boolean before you open Gallery or File Manager and change it when you already got result what you wanted.

Comment: glad you found an answer to your question, even better that you found it yourself, those are rare events these days